# Constructive Strong Normalization of the Extended Calculus of Constructions

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, dependent-type, typed-lambda-calculus

The extended calculus of constructions (ECC) is basically the calculus of constructions with cumulative universes. I use the definition which Zhaohui Luo used in his PhD theses which contained a proof of strong normalization of the calculus.

Unfortunately the strong normalization proof presented in Luo's thesis is not contructive (as far as I understand). It uses the definition of the level of a type which is defined as the lowest universe a type lives in modulo conversion. The definition is classically sound since the universes form a wellorder and therefore a nonempty set of universes must have a least element. However I don't see any possibility to give a constructive definition of the level of a type.

Having no constructive definition of the level of a type, I am not able to make a constructive version of Luo's proof of strong normalisation. This implies to me that I cannot write a type checker for ECC e.g. in Coq without using axioms.

Is this result general? Is it impossible to write a typechecker for ECC in Coq?

This restriction would be rather unfortunate, because it would draw a strict line between the calculus of constructions where the strong normalization can be proved constructively and ECC where no such proof is possible.

Any comments hints on this topic?

Comment: Can you replace the ordinary natural numbers with [upper numbers](https://twitter.com/andrejbauer/status/1394317732494159874?s=20)? That is, the level of a term $t$ is the set of all $n$ such that $t : U_n$. I uppose then the problem is convincing Coq that upper numbers have a suitable inductive property. But there should be one, at least for monotone predicates, and maybe your predicates are monotone. (I am just shooting in the dark here.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer: This might be an excellent hint. The set of all universes a type resides in is always upper closed because of cumulativity. Therefore I can use a predicate which describes the set of all universes of a type and use it instead of the level. As far as I know, Luo's proof only uses order expressions on levels which might be replaceable by order expression on predicates as well. I have to look into the details, but is sounds promising.

Comment: What bothers me is that I don't see how to derive an induction principle for upper numbers in Coq. You might need something like that somewhere.